# Which semantic element I should use to wrap all the child elements?

Tags: html

I’m learning `semantic HTML` and trying to figure out which element should be used after `<body>` element to wrap all the child semantic elements ?

I’m doing as below

```
<div class="grid-container">
```

can I replace `div` with `main` here as wrapper element for all ?

Are there `any rules for semantic elements` like which can be child and which can’t also other good practices ?

As HTML is not strict and doesn’t complain about any mistakes done wrt semantic elements usage, but for SEO, Accessibility I would like to follow best practices.

Comment: I guess this cannot be answered without knowing what your site actually contains. You'd choose the proper tag for whatever your div contains, but whether that's an article, section or whatever is up to the content's nature.

Comment: @maio290 Please refer to example github.com/iamshaunjp/css-grid-layouts/blob/finished-files/…, why can't I apply class "grid-container" on <body> element itself instead of creating new <div> container ?

Answer (score 0):

SEO does not care about which tags you use. HTML validity does help, though. But the difference between using a `<div>` and `<main>` does not matter.

Semantically, `<main>` is the better choice because `<div>` has no special meaning at all.

[The main element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/grouping-content.html#the-main-element)

> The main element represents the dominant contents of the document.

Comment: More broadly speaking, if the choice is ever between `div` and some element X, both of which represent the thing you want, then X is probably the better choice, since `div` basically says "it's a block and that's all I know." Same for `span`.

Comment: Please refer to example https://github.com/iamshaunjp/css-grid-layouts/blob/finished-files/3%20-%20holy-grail/index.html#L10, why can't I apply class "grid-container" on <body> element itself instead of creating new <div> container ?

Comment: @vikramvi You should open a new question for that.